# PLSQL dynamic query

Tags: oracle, plsql, dynamic-sql

I have a table A which has column `A` which holds table names as values.
All these tables have a common column `C`. I need maximum value of this column for each table.

I tried this using dynamic SQL but I'm getting errors. Please suggest.

```
DECLARE    
 query1 VARCHAR2(100);
 c_table VARCHAR2(40);
 c_obj VARCHAR2(20);
 Cursor cursor_a IS
 SELECT a FROM A;  
BEGIN
Open cursor_a;
   LOOP
      Fetch cursor_a INTO c_table2;      
      EXIT WHEN cursor_a%notfound;     
      query1 := 'SELECT max(object_ref) AS "c_obj" FROM c_table' ;
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE query1;
      dbms_output.put_line('Maximum value: '|| c_table || c_obj);
   END LOOP;
Close cursor_a;
END;
```

Comment: "*but getting errors*" - and the errors are?

Answer (score 2):

Dynamic SQL can't see your PL/SQL variable: you need to pass it a string which can be executed in the scope of the SQL engine.  So you need to concatenate the table name with the statement's boilerplate text:

```
query1 := 'SELECT max(c)  FROM ' || variable_name;
```

You also need to return the result of the query into a variable.

Here is how it works (I've stripped out some of the unnecessary code from your example):

```
DECLARE    
 c_table VARCHAR2(40);
 c_obj VARCHAR2(20);
BEGIN
   for lrec in ( select a as tab_name from A )
   LOOP
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT max(object_ref)  FROM ' || lrec.tab_name 
           into c_obj ;
      dbms_output.put_line('Maximum value: '|| lrec.tab_name
           || '='|| c_obj);
   END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: Since OP's stated "*All these tables have a common column `C`*" it should be rather `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT max(C)  FROM ' || lrec.tab_name into c_obj ;`

Answer (score -4):

There is some miss match in veriables that you had used i.e.

1. declared as "**c_table**" but accessing as "**c_table2**"
2. Each table common column name is "**C**" but accessing as "**object_ref**"
3. In dynamic query use **INTO** keyword to store the value to your varibale

**Suggestions**

1. Use concat() function to prepare the query dynamically i.e. something like:

   SET @SQL := CONCAT('SELECT max(c) INTO ', c_obj, ' FROM ',c_table);
2. Steps of implementing dynamic query is:

   ```
   SET @SQL = <your dynamic query>
   PREPARE stmt FROM @SQL;
   EXECUTE stmt;
   ```

**Sample code:**

```
DECLARE    
 query1 VARCHAR2(100);
 c_table VARCHAR2(40);
 c_obj VARCHAR2(20);
 CURSOR cursor_a IS
 SELECT a FROM A;  
BEGIN
OPEN cursor_a;
   LOOP
      FETCH cursor_a INTO c_table;      
      EXIT WHEN cursor_a%notfound; 
      SET @SQL := CONCAT('SELECT max(object_ref) AS c_obj INTO ', c_obj, ' FROM ',c_table);
    PREPARE stmt FROM @SQL;         
    EXECUTE stmt;    
    dbms_output.put_line('Maximum value: '|| c_table || c_obj);
   END LOOP;
CLOSE cursor_a;
END;
```

Comment: This is not valid Oracle PL/SQL syntax

Comment: Yeah it is sample way to run dynamic query (reference syntax: is for MySQL compatible), you make require changes based on database you are using i.e. Oracle

Comment: StackOverflow has lots of MySQL questions.  Why not answer some of them?  Unless you want to take this as a chance to teach yourself Oracle PL/SQL by answering the question with a solution which actually **meets the OP's requirements** .

Comment: That's neither valid MySQL nor valid Oracle syntax

Comment: Yeah this answer is suggestion towards the approach, where I tried to figure out area of problems and given a refrence solution. Make require changes based on Oracle DB  Thank you for your kind suggestion, I will work on it...APC

Comment: Then make it clear in the answer it's a pseudo code.

Comment: It's clearly mentioned as suggestion.. Sample Code...... don't go for language formation