# How can pass table name in cursor as parameter?

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle11g

I have a procedure with cursor querying an external table. How can I pass the table name in `select`?

```
procedure ImpInsData(fileN varchar2,Tname VARCHAR2)
as
begin
   IXRBI.EXternalChange ( fileN,Tname);      
   declare
      cursor cur_extenal is select * from Tname WHERE A IN ('1','2');
   begin 
      FOR rec IN cur_extenal LOOP 
         vId :=sys_guid();
         vRowStatus:=rec.A;
         vTag:=rec.C;
       end loop
   end;
end;
```

Tname is a parameter specifying a table name.

How can I rewrite it?

Comment: you cant, really!

Comment: Check out "open for using". A quick Google search found an example at [This location](http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/ora/plsql/cursors/dynamic.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
procedure ImpInsData(fileN varchar2)
as
CURSOR cur_extenal IS
(
select * from Tname WHERE A IN ('1','2')
);
begin
open cur_extenal

FETCH cur_extenal into rec
      FOR rec IN cur_extenal LOOP 
         vId :=sys_guid();
         vRowStatus:=rec.A;
         vTag:=rec.C;
exit when cur_extenal%notfound;
       end loop;
close cur_extenal;
   end;
```

Comment: This answer rewrites the OP's posted code but does not actually solve their problem. A correct answer requires the use of dynamic SQL, such [my answer in this other SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29693016/146325).